# How to install PEAR with MAMP for OS X?

Tags: php, pear, php-5.3, mamp, authentication

I'm trying to get PEAR working with MAMP. I'm running the following [Auth example](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.authentication.auth.intro.php) from the PEAR website:

```
<?php
require_once "Auth.php";

// Takes three arguments: last attempted username, the authorization
// status, and the Auth object. 
// We won't use them in this simple demonstration -- but you can use them
// to do neat things.
function loginFunction($username = null, $status = null, &$auth = null)
{
    /*
     * Change the HTML output so that it fits to your
     * application.
     */
    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"test.php\">";
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\">";
    echo "<input type=\"password\" name=\"password\">";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\">";
    echo "</form>";
}

$options = array(
  'dsn' => "mysql://user:password@localhost/database",
  );
$a = new Auth("DB", $options, "loginFunction");

$a->start();

if ($a->checkAuth()) {
    /*
     * The output of your site goes here.
     */
}
?>
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Auth.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php')
```

I have PEAR installed and can even run `pear` from the command line, but I am completely stuck trying to get PEAR:Auth to run in this example code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include PEAR path in you `include_path` in php.ini http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

In that path should be the file `Auth.php`, so you can look it up and then getting its parent directory absolute path

Comment: This was something I had tried over and over with no results, causing me incredible frustation. Turns out, this is the correct answer, but MAMP doesn't use the local copy of php.ini and instead creates a new version from a template file each time it restarts. Once I added the PEAR directory to the template's include_path, things started working. Thanks for your help.